# Change Date Format from '-' to '/'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How to update or change date format `"%Y-/%m-/%d"` to `"%Y/%m/%d"` in my sql. After refreshing it goes to normal '-' format.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Quality questions with detail oriented descriptions receive the best quality answers. Also, please be sure to post the SQL that you have already tried. Here are tips to help you out: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers!

Comment: What query are you running?

Answer (score 0):

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html :

> MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. However, it will recognize the (input) format to a date field in any of 'YYYY-MM-DD' or 'YY-MM-DD' or 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'YYYY^MM^DD' and 'YYYY@MM@DD' or even YYYYMMDD.

If you want to display a date in a different format (e.g. your chosen format of YYYY/MM/DD), then you need to change the format in the query string. Consider this example below

I have a table with 3 fields id, Date and Amount. If I run the query

```
SELECT id, Date, Amount FROM `dtdata` ORDER BY `dtdata`.`id` ASC
```

I get the output as shown:

[image]

If I want to display the date differently (i.e. your required format), I can use the following Query:

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(Date, "%Y/%m/%d") AS NewDate, Amount FROM `dtdata`
```

to get the output as

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Martin - assistance much appreciated

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it will not give permanent solution . it is only view select purpose , I want to change my data permanently .

Answer (score 0):

just use select DATE_FORMAT(yourdatecolumn, "%Y/%m/%d")
example

```
select DATE_FORMAT('2018-08-01', "%Y/%m/%d")

 2018/08/01
```